# How to log backend in varnishncsa client mode log format?

Tags: varnish

I'm looking for a way to include the backend name (as configured by the `backend` vcl option), that a request was sent to (or response received from; either way) in `varnishncsa` log output.

When running varnishncsa in *client mode*, i.e. logging the frontend requests/responses.

The log format is here: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishncsa.html#format

I've tried to find an "Extended variable" (`%{X}x`) that would satisfy this option, without luck so far. Varnish version is 6.x.

Do I need to set a custom request or response header, to match on, for this first??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an *extended variable* to get the job done.

### `varnishncsa` from a backend request

Here's an example where I retrieve the backend name for backend requests:

```
varnishncsa -b -F "%{VSL:BackendOpen[2]}x"
```

The *VSL tag* you need is the `BackendOpen` tag that would return the following output in `varnishlog`:

```
-   BackendOpen    32 boot.bla 192.168.224.2 8080 192.168.224.3 53908
```

As you can see the *backend name* is the second field, hence the `BackendOpen[2]` expression.

### `varnishncsa` from a client request

In the *client thread* the backend is *hinted*, but not opened.

If you want to access the *hinted* backend, you'll need to have access to the `req.backend_hint` variable. You could use `std.log()` to log this value as a `VCL_Log` tag.

Here's the VCL example:

```
vcl 4.0;
import std;

backend default {
  .host="1.2.3.4";
  .port="80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
  std.log("Backend: "+ req.backend_hint);
}
```

And here's the `varnishncsa` command the would look for this value:

```
varnishncsa -c -F "%{VSL:VCL_Log:Backend}x"
```

### Conclusion

Of course you still need to tune your `varnishncsa` command a bit to include the right fields and filter on the right parameters, but this one should hopefully answer your question.

It's up to you to look for the backend name at *client request* side or at the *backend request* side.

Comment: It seems `%{VSL:VCL_Log:Backend}x` is equal to `%{VCL_Log:Backend}x`, there? Thanks also for the `%{VSL:BackendOpen[2]}x` mention, that field index field now makes sense! And it seems to work nicely :)